# angular auto mocking controller/service dependencies

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking

In Angular unit testing, it takes a lot of unnecessary code to mock/stub all depencencies manually, especially when all I need are some generic mocks. Also, when dependency list changes for service/controller, tests break because of missing dependencies.

In C#, there is a way to reconfigure DI container to automatically mock all dependencies, when Resolve() is called. I want something like that in Angular.

I want to go from this:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, agsRest) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();      

        sut = $controller('SearchController', {
            $scope: scope
            , map: {}
            , agsRest: agsRest
            , config: {}
            , core: {}
            , myPopup: {}
            , popupFormatter: {}
        });
    }));
```

To something like this:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, agsRest) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();      

        sut = autoMock("SearchController"); // instance of SearchController is returned, which has all dependencies mocked with sinon/jasmine/whatever
    }));
```

Is there some kind of library / code to do this?

Comment: No. But you don't need to mock *everything*, just what you are going to use in the test, right?

Comment: Sometimes. But I still need to create and pass all dependencies when using $controller('SearchController', { ... }); And that takes a lot of manual writing.

Answer (score 1):

I've needed something similar and came up with this small utility library: [tentacle.js](https://github.com/anilanar/tentacle.js). I'm up to suggestions and to pull requests for bettering the API.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for **ng-improved-testing**. It's create auto-mock for all injected services (you need only add "Mock" to services name when you inject them).

Link to GitHub: 
https://github.com/evangalen/ng-improved-testing